# How to copy an email to a office 365 group?

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-js

I am trying to write a outlook add-in that allow you to copy email to a office 365 group. Does office.js allow you to do that? More specifically, how can I, using office.js

- Find the office 365 group that I am interested in
- Copy the email to the specific group

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, office js does not support this, so i think you can submit an feature request in the [uservoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback):

Similar quesiton on moving mail to group but not use office JS:
https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/286611-office-365-groups/suggestions/15152328-move-copy-e-mails-from-mailboxes-to-office365-grou. Based on the reply, we can use VBA to implement this: record an macro and change the code to suit our requirement